# After updating to Watch OS 9.0 my app is getting NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet error

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

After updating to Watch OS 9 my app suddenly cannot connect to the internet with my app using a NSURLSession. It gets an error "Path was denied by NECP policy " and NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet every time. But this still works fine on Watch OS 8 and in the simulator.

I'm definitely connected to the Internet over WIFI on my Watch and iPhone. Are there any new requirements in Watch OS 9 to get internet access, such as request permission from the user or adding anything to info.plist? What else could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems, apple just silently dropped the support for non-audio-player apps with watch os9.

It seems you can still use it, if you are an „audio player“ app.

Other people are complaining as well:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715024